# I have a problem with menubar buttons in Kibana

Tags: kibana

I installed the Opendistro version of kibana, installed from the Debian package
`opendistroforelasticsearch-kibana`
I have Elasticsearch-oss 7.7.0 installed and running, apparently without any error

But when I login in Kibana, the sidebar menu buttons are not working. Is like I only can see the "Server Status" page. For example cliking the "Management" menu button, nothing happend. Clicking for example "Anomally detection" button, it reloads the same page.

In the syslog I can see this, that doesn ' t seem  to me any problem:

```
Jul  1 03:06:18 server-control kibana[5282]: {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2020-07-01T03:06:18Z","tags":[],"pid":5282,"method":"post","statusCode":200,"req":{"url":"/api/ui_metric/report","method":"post","headers":{"host":"10.0.1.1:5601","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux aarch64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0","accept":"*/*","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.5","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate","referer":"http://10.0.1.1:5601/app/opendistro-anomaly-detection-kibana","content-type":"application/json","kbn-version":"7.7.0","origin":"http://10.0.1.1:5601","content-length":"306","connection":"keep-alive","securitytenant":"__user__"},"remoteAddress":"10.0.1.3","userAgent":"10.0.1.3","referer":"http://10.0.1.1:5601/app/opendistro-anomaly-detection-kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":200,"responseTime":9,"contentLength":9},"message":"POST /api/ui_metric/report 200 9ms - 9.0B"}
```

AT this point the only warning I can found is this, at the beginning of running
`kibana --verbose`

```
  log   [03:18:45.488] [info][OpenDistro Security Migration] Starting tenant migration
 error  [03:18:45.515] [error][migration] Error: Authorization Exception: Authorization Exception
    at respond (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:349:15)
    at checkRespForFailure (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:306:7)
    at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:173:7)
    at IncomingMessage.wrapper (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/elasticsearch/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4929:19)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

thanks

Debian 10

Comment: seems to me some kind of permissions problem...still working on it.

Comment: now it evolves to this new error (Kibana not starting): "Error: Unable to write Kibana UUID file, please check the uuid.server configuration value in kibana.yml and ensure Kibana has sufficient permissions to read / write to this file. Error was: EACCES"

Answer (score 0):

Solved

It was a problem with permissions. Solved purging, reinstalling opendistroforelasicsearch with only one plugin, manual installed (the security one).
Then resintalled opendistroforelasticsearch-kibana, and here cames the amazing solution...first run with sudo --allow-root.
And after that succesful first run, all the conventional non-sudo runs are working properly